# Tinker giving exception in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, tinker

[image: Writing to /home/vishu/ .config/psysh is not allowed]

[image: Laravel Project Permissions]

Exception: Writing to /home/vishu/.config/psysh is not allowed.

at /usr/share/nginx/html/example/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:228

```
 @\mkdir($dir, 0700, true);
         }

         if (!\is_dir($dir) || !\is_writable($dir)) {
           \trigger_error(\sprintf('Writing to %s is not allowed.', $dir), E_USER_NOTICE);

             return false;
         }
```

Comment: Did you check file permission? And you should try to give more detail info about question, not just paste code/log/images, see [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 storage

Comment: Solution suggested by bernhardh on github is modification of the location by setting the following to .env                                                      XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/path/to/new/location             but I am not getting setting of the path thing in Vendor/../Xdg.php

Comment: You're only checking if dir is writable and if it's a dir but not if you have permissions to modify it.

Comment: I have permission to write it.                                                                                 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vishu www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/example/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php

Answer (score 0):

If the project is in development state, you can change the whole `storage` directory permission to 777:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Comment: Giving  permission 777  is a bad idea even though it is in development stage.

Comment: I have changed permissions for Log  to 775.Now Error is  Writing to /home/vishu/.config/psysh is not allowed.

  at /usr/share/nginx/html/example/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:228

Comment: this did not work for me.